# Update document in cosmos DB with logic app

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Im trying to add new objects in my CosmosDB Item using LogicApp.

```js
{
  "id": "1000",
  "phone": "55512341212"
}
```

to

```js
{
  "id": "1000",
  "phone": "55512341212"',
  "name":"David"
}
```

I works if I use "Create or Update a Document" but I have to know the existing content and overwrite. How to just add "name":"David" without knowing the content ?
Thanks!
David

Answer (score 1):

Partial updates are not currently possible with Cosmos DB. You must write the entire record back using ReplaceItemAsync() or UpsertItemAsync().

Comment: Partial updates are currently being worked on now. However, you still will need the partition key and id to do the update.

Comment: Thanks! how to be alerted when released ?

Comment: Can track it on User Voice, https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6693091-be-able-to-do-partial-updates-on-document

Comment: It looks like this is no longer available , as the link is dead